# What numerical methods can be used to verify the accuracy of Feynman diagram results?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, computational-physics, feynman-diagrams, path-integral

Recently, I have been attempting to replicate the Feynman diagram calculation which was featured in an article  [here](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.98.195103).

\begin{align}
 &C_{x y x y}^{1, e}(i \Omega)= -(1-\delta)  r_0^{-\delta} 2^{4+\delta} \pi \frac{\Gamma[(3+\delta) / 2]}{\Gamma[(3-\delta) / 2]} \int \frac{d^2 \boldsymbol{k}}{(2 \pi)^2} \int \frac{d^2 \boldsymbol{l}}{(2 \pi)^2} \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d \alpha^{\prime}}{2 \pi} \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d \alpha}{2 \pi} \frac{l_x l_y}{l^{\delta+3}} \operatorname{Tr} \notag\\
 &\left[-\frac{i \alpha^{\prime}+ \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot(\boldsymbol{k}+\boldsymbol{l})}{\alpha^{\prime 2}+( |\boldsymbol{k}+\boldsymbol{l}|)^2}\right]\left[-\frac{i(\alpha+\Omega)+ \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{k}}{(\alpha+\Omega)^2+k^2}\right] \frac{ \left(k_x \sigma_y+k_y \sigma_x\right)}{2}\left[-\frac{i \alpha+  \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{k}}{\alpha^2+k^2}\right],\notag\
\end{align}
where $\boldsymbol{k}$ and $\boldsymbol{l}$ are momentum of electrons in two dimension, $\boldsymbol{\sigma} $ are Pauli matrices, $r_{0}$ is a constant, $\delta$ is an infinitesimal constant and take the limit $\delta\rightarrow 0$ at the end.

Following a thorough calculation, and analytical continuation to real frequencies $i \Omega \rightarrow \omega+i \delta$, we can arrive at the expression $$\frac{\operatorname{Im} C_{x y x y}^{(1, e)}}{\omega}   = \frac{2^{2 \delta-8}(\delta-1) \omega^{-\delta} r_0^{-\delta} \Gamma(\delta / 2)}{\Gamma(3-\delta / 2)} \omega^2.$$

To ensure accuracy of the results, I wish to validate the analytical results through numerical method. However, it is challenging to integrate the original expression, as the integrand is a highly oscillatory function. How can we numerically verify the accuracy of the above results?

---

To make numerical calculation easier, I need to preprocess the expression. It has been noted that the trace consists of four components, with the $\alpha^{\prime}$ of the first component being zero after the integration is completed. Consequently, the expression can be reduced to
\begin{align}
 &C_{x y x y}^{1, e}(i \Omega)= -(1-\delta)  r_0^{-\delta} 2^{4+\delta} \pi \frac{\Gamma[(3+\delta) / 2]}{\Gamma[(3-\delta) / 2]} \int \frac{d^2 \boldsymbol{k}}{(2 \pi)^2} \int \frac{d^2 \boldsymbol{l}}{(2 \pi)^2} \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d \alpha^{\prime}}{2 \pi} \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d \alpha}{2 \pi} \frac{l_x l_y}{l^{\delta+3}} \operatorname{Tr}  \left[-\frac{  \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot(\boldsymbol{k}+\boldsymbol{l})}{\alpha^{\prime 2}+( |\boldsymbol{k}+\boldsymbol{l}|)^2}\right]\left[-\frac{i(\alpha+\Omega)+ \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{k}}{(\alpha+\Omega)^2+k^2}\right] \frac{ \left(k_x \sigma_y+k_y \sigma_x\right)}{2}\left[-\frac{i \alpha+  \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{k}}{\alpha^2+k^2}\right],\notag\
\end{align}
Integrating $ \alpha $ and $ \alpha ^ { \prime} $ yields
$$C_{x y x y}^{1, e}(i \Omega)= \int_{0}^{\infty} dk\int_{0}^{\infty} dl\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta_{k}\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta_{l}\frac{2^{\delta } k^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{\delta +3}{2}\right) \cos (2 \theta _k) \sin (2 \theta _l) l^{-\delta } r_{0}^{-\delta } \sin (\theta _k-\theta _l)}{\pi ^3 \Gamma \left( \frac{1-\delta }{2}\right) \left(4 k^2+\Omega ^2\right) \sqrt{k^2+2 k l \cos (\theta _k-\theta _l)+l^2}}$$
Let us assume that $\delta=0.1$, $r_{0}=1$, and $\Omega=-0.2i$, and then use Mathematica for numerical integration. The result of the calculation is unsatisfactory because singularity or highly-oscillatory integration may be present.

---

The code I formulated using Mathmatica is displayed below.

```
Clear["`*"]

equ=-(1-\[Delta])*r0^-\[Delta]*2^(\[Delta]+4)*Pi*Gamma[(3+\[Delta])/2]/Gamma[(3-\[Delta])/2]*(-1)*(-1)*(1/2)*(-1)*1/(2*Pi)^6*1/(\[Alpha]prime^2+(Sqrt[(kx+lx)^2+(ky+ly)^2])^2)*1/((\[Alpha]+\[CapitalOmega])^2+k^2)*1/(\[Alpha]^2+k^2)*(lx*ly)/l^(3+\[Delta])*Tr[(I*0*PauliMatrix[0]+PauliMatrix[1]*(kx+lx)+PauliMatrix[2]*(ky+ly)).(I*(\[Alpha]+\[CapitalOmega])*PauliMatrix[0]+PauliMatrix[1]*kx+PauliMatrix[2]*ky).(kx*PauliMatrix[2]+ky*PauliMatrix[1]).(I*\[Alpha]*PauliMatrix[0]+PauliMatrix[1]*kx+PauliMatrix[2]*ky)];
equ2=equ/.{lx->l*Cos[\[Theta]l],ly->l*Sin[\[Theta]l],kx->k*Cos[\[Theta]k],ky->k*Sin[\[Theta]k]};
equ3=FullSimplify[Integrate[equ2,{\[Alpha]prime,-Infinity,Infinity},{\[Alpha],-Infinity,Infinity}],k>0]
NIntegrate[equ3/.{\[Delta]->0.1,r0->1,\[CapitalOmega]->-0.2*I},{\[Theta]k,0,2*Pi},{\[Theta]l,0,2*Pi},{k,0,Infinity},{l,0,Infinity}]
```

Comment: *The integrand is a highly oscillatory function.* Can you explain what is oscillatory about it? The integrand appears to be a rational function of the six integration variables.

Comment: There's a learning curve for setting up numerical Feynman integrals this way, but I've had good results with the packages at https://mbtools.hepforge.org/